# Won't or doesn't? If either works, what's the difference?

Tags: test

The weather is windy and the wind is blowing outside. I am sitting in front of the TV, but it …………… turn on and I don’t know what I should do to fix it.

Comment: I'm surprised to find this question being downvoted!

Answer (score 4):

They mean different things. They may or may not ***"work"***. Depending on what the speaker wants.

The *will* of *It won't turn on* is the [Deontic Modal *will](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/modals.html)*, meaning *(be) willing (to)*. Since television sets are not capable of willing, this must mean failure to turn on has been diagnosed as a persistent "habit" (i.e, tendency) of the TV. Hence there is an invoked history. And a personification of the TV set as having moods.

The *do* of *It doesn't turn on*, on the other hand, is simply ordinary *Do*-Support, with no special meaning at all, and therefore -- by contrast with *will* -- it carries the sense of a first encounter, an *alls-I-know-is-it-didn't-turn-on* event.

Aside from that, no difference in this case. Other cases, of course, will vary.